# Why does the standard Bitcoin message signature include a "magic prefix?"

Tags: message-signing

The standard Bitcoin message signature works as follows:

```
sign(sha256(magicPrefix . length(message) . message))
```

The "magic prefix" is simply the string `'\x18Bitcoin Signed Message:\n'`, where 0x18 is the length of the prefix text.

In other words, it's this:

```
sign(sha256(length(prefix) . prefix . length(message) . message))
```

My question is:

1. Why does it use a magic prefix?
2. Why does it include the lengths of the two components?

I'm asking mainly from a security point of view. Does adding a prefix or including the length(s) have any security benefits? If not, I'd like to drop it from my signatures.

Comment: Is this from the C++ code? Because I saw similar code in pybitcointools' `electrum_sig_hash` function

Comment: It's also in BitcoinJS: https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/1079bf95c1095f7fb018f6e4757277d83b7b9d07/src/message.js#L13

Comment: The duplicate doesn't address the inclusion of the lengths. The answer is that it's to definitively protect against [length extension attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack).

Answer (score 0):

[RFC4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.2.1) apparently standardises the way signatures work, so it *could* be referring to:

> 0x18: Subkey Binding Signature
> This signature is a statement by the top-level signing key that
> indicates that it owns the subkey.  This signature is calculated
> directly on the primary key and subkey, and not on any User ID or
> other packets.  A signature that binds a signing subkey MUST have
> an Embedded Signature subpacket in this binding signature that
> contains a 0x19 signature made by the signing subkey on the
> primary key and subkey.

But it seems much more likely [BIP70 extension proposal](https://github.com/bitid/bitid/blob/master/bip70_extension.md) is the reason for standardising signatures, as outlined by their BitID [wallet implementation requirements](https://github.com/bitid/bitid#wallet-implementation-requirements):

> To be compatible with the BitID protocol, a wallet must implement the following:
>
> - register the bitid scheme
> - throw a bitid intent when scanning a BitID QR code (if applicable)
> - decode the URI and verify its format
> - display a request for authentication showing the domain name callback and > - ask for validation
> - ask the user to pick up or create a Bitcoin address for the authentication (show the last Bitcoin address used if this is a known callback address)
> - ***sign the BitID URI with the private key (using the \x18Bitcoin Signed Message:\n#{message.size.chr}#{message} convention)***
> - POST the signature and the public key to the callback URL
>   completion dialog : success/retry/cancel

Comment: It would have been much better if you actually explained and not citing the documents.